# (GitHub) Removing the only collaborator from a repo created under an organization?

Tags: git, github

Say you have created a repository and added it to an organization on GitHub, and you are the only person listed as a Collaborator.

If you remove yourself as a collaborator, does the entire organization including yourself lose access to the repository? Assuming there were other people with admin/read/write access to the repository before this, but who were not "collaborators"?

Comment: I think if you are the admin of the org, you will still have access to that repo.

Answer (score -1):

An Organization must always have an Owner.  GitHub won't let you remove all owners.